# Why does my scipy build break?

Tags: c, gcc, scipy

I am new to scientific computing and trying to contribute to `scipy` but I can't get it to build.

I `git clone`'d the source then ran `python setup.py build`. I get a break saying:

> scipy/special/cephes/bdtr.c: In function ‘cephes_bdtrc’:
>   scipy/special/cephes/bdtr.c:157:5: error: non-floating-point argument in call to function ‘__builtin_isnan’
>   if (npy_isnan(k) || npy_isnan(n) || npy_isnan(p)) {

Ubuntu 16.04, Intel i7. For other work I have Anaconda 1.6.3 installed. Python 2.7.13 and gfortran.

I followed the setup [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/hacking.html#recommended-development-setup) and [here](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html#debian-ubuntu).

Any ideas? Maybe a gcc switch?

Comment: did you also run `sudo apt-get install gcc gfortran python-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev cython` ?

Comment: @percusse Yep, sure did.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but I would just install Anaconda (current is  5.0.1) from scratch, which includes scipy (plus lots of other useful things).

Comment: @user8153 I want to contribute to scipy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in this particular scipy/numpy combination.  `n` and `k` are integer variables, so they cannot be NaNs, introduced in [commit ede5590b12dbeecd244fdafa4443b6c3a9d9ef40 (BUG: special: fix ufunc results for `nan` arguments)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/ede5590b12dbeecd244fdafa4443b6c3a9d9ef40).

You could change the reported line locally to

```
    if (npy_isnan(p)) {
```

until the issue is fixed upstream.

Comment: I upgraded from numpy 1.11.2 -> 1.13.1 via `conda update --all` and pulled the latest scipy repo with fix for this bug and now I can build. Thanks!